# Why window.showOpenFilePicker is undefined in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, html5-filesystem

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Origin_private_file_system) the Origin private file system is supported from Firefox 111 but I'm using Firefox 120 and the function:

```
window.showOpenFilePicker
```

is undefined. Why is that? Was it removed from Firefox? Or do I need to setup something to use this API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `showOpenFilePicker` method is part of the [File System Access API](https://wicg.github.io/file-system-access/), which is not a WhatWG or W3C standard, and not implemented by Firefox. The File System Access API extends the WhatWG standard [File System API](https://fs.spec.whatwg.org/) (a.k.a "origin private file system"), which is fully supported by Firefox. Mozilla considers the File System Access API partly [harmful](https://mozilla.github.io/standards-positions/#native-file-system), thus an implementation is unlikely to happen in the near future.